# How to animate appearing element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I have this React code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./UpcomingEvent.module.css";
import Button from "../UI/Button";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faClock } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";

const Event = ({ event }) => {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseIn = () => {
    setIsHover(true);
  };

  const handleMouseOut = () => {
    setIsHover(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={styles.event}
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseIn}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseOut}
    >
      <div className={styles["event-image"]}>
        <img src={event.imageUrl} alt={event.name} />
      </div>
      {isHover && (
        <div className={styles["event-info"]}>
          <h3>{event.name}</h3>
          <p className={styles.date}>
            {`${event.type} | `}
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock} />
            {` ${event.date}`}
          </p>
          <p className={styles.desc}>{event.description}</p>
          <Button type="button" className={styles.button}>
            Sign up!
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Event;
```

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "latobold";
  src: url(../../fonts/lato-bold-webfont.woff2) format("woff2"),
    url(../../fonts/lato-bold-webfont.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.event {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.event:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: right;
}

.event:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.event-info {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.event-image img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.event-info h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  padding: 0;
  color: #2e294e;
}

.date,
.desc {
  color: #5f0f40;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.date {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.button {
  border: solid 3px #2e294e;
  color: #2e294e;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1rem 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #2e294e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I want to animate .event-info when it appears after hovering over .event component. Do you have any idea how could i do it? I have tried with transiotion property, but it didnt work. I would like to achive a walk in effect.

I have tried transition and transform properties but nothing seems to work.